# what is the data type of object when passing to another class in scala ? or how to pass an object type as a parameter to another class?

Tags: class, scala, object, actor

In the below code, i want to pass profileobj to UserActor class, but what is the type i should specify for this, for now as you can see, i put the type as Any, but this is not working.

```
case class Profile(i: Int, j: Double)

object Local {
    def main(args: Array[String]){    
        profileobj = new Profile(10, 20)
        var k = 30 ;
    }
} 
val userActor = system.actorOf(Props(new UserActor(profileobj, k)), name = username)

class UserActor(profileobj: Any, k: Int) extends Actor {
    var a: Int = profileobj1.i 

}
```

I am getting the error as,

```
value i is not a member of Any
var a: Int = profileobj1.i
```

If not this, is there any other way for me to pass this object to UserActor class ?

Comment: It's of type `Profile`, no? Or is there some more subtle issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's `Local.type` - the name of the object followed by the type keyword.

You can read more about this in my [Scala's Types of Types](http://ktoso.github.io/scala-types-of-types/#type-of-an-code-object-code) compendium.